# How does the physics definition of a non-spontaneous process not violate logic?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

**The Second Law of Thermodynamics and The Law of Excluded Middle**

(The Definition of 'Non-Spontaneous' in Physics vs. in Logic)

A thermodynamic process can only belong to one of the following options:

- Spontaneous (& Irreversible): ΔSuniv > 0
- Equilibrium (& Reversible): ΔSuniv = 0
- Non-Spontaneous (& Irreversible): ΔSuniv < 0

The naming convention for the type of processes: (ΔS>0), (ΔS=0), (ΔS<0) violates the law of excluded middle (X V ~X).

The physics naming convention is logically unsound, that is, the nomenclature: i.e., definitions of spontaneous, non-spontaneous, and equilibrium process are violate bivalent (i.e., {true, false}) propositional logic by violating the law of excluded middle (:= LEM): X V ~X.

**The Problem:** Not Spontaneous (ΔS ≤0) ≠ Non-Spontaneous (ΔS <0).
LEM: Law of Excluded Middle: (X V ~X)
Either a proposition X is true or its negation ~X (i.e., ‘not X’) is true:

- X: = ‘The process is spontaneous.”
- ~X: = ‘The process is *not* spontaneous”

  ```
   **LEM:** [X V ~X] <--> [X and/or ~X] <--> [X i.or ~X];
  ```

where: '<-->' denotes "materially equivalent" (i.e., materially imply one another).
**Note:** ‘V’: inclusive conjunction: ‘i.or’.

Either a process (X) is spontaneous or not, and it cannot be neither one. A process must be either one option or the other. However, the physics definition of a non-spontaneous process does not match the definition which would be logically sound (let’s call this the ‘logical definition’). Here, I explain how the physics definition is inconsistent with the logical definition, i.e., it permits for a logical impossibility, namely that there can be a middle between or otherwise third option besides some proposition X and its logical negation ~X (i.e., ~X).

The second law of thermodynamics states that the entropy of the universe increases for a spontaneous process, where the entropy of the universe is the entropy of a given 'system' (i.e., control volume designated as the system of interest, plus the entropy of its 'surroundings'(i.e., everything else in the universe but the system.) Another equivalent way to state this would be to say that the entropy change of the universe is positive in a spontaneous (irreversible) process: (ΔS > 0), is zero in an equilibrium (reversible) process: (ΔS = 0), and it is negative for a non-spontaneous process: (ΔS < 0).

**Spontaneity vs. Entropy Change of the Universe:**

- Spontaneous: ΔS > 0
- Non-Spontaneous: ΔS < 0
- Equilibrium: ΔS = 0

Physics:
ΔS > 0: Spontaneous:
ΔS < 0: Non-Spontaneous:
ΔS = 0: Equilibrium
Logic:
ΔS > 0: Spontaneous
ΔS ≤ 0: Non-Spontaneous

The term “non-spontaneous” should apply to the types of processes that are ‘not spontaneous’: that is, ‘non-spontaneous’ and ‘equilibrium’; however, in physics, it only applies to the one termed ‘non-spontaneous’ and excludes the term ‘equilibrium’. By definition, ‘not spontaneous’ = ‘non-spontaneous’, at least according to the most normative usage of the negation operator ('not'). However, this is not how the negation is treated according to the physics naming scheme for the three possible options for a process (ΔS: {+, 0, -}).

```
- Spontaneous process: {real, irreversible, actual → possible in reality}
- Equilibrium: ideal → {ideal → not real, reversible, impossible in reality}
- Non-Spontaneous: {not real, irreversible, impossible in reality}
```

Q1: Isn’t the nomenclature accepted in physics logically unsound?
Q2: How can the physics definition be made compatible with the logic definition*

I don’t see they how they do not conflict. Please, explain how to square these two definitions with one another.
Law of Excluded Middle (LEM): [X V ~X]

- X :=    Ξ(x): = ‘—x— is spontaneous.’
- ~X := ~Ξ(x): = ‘—x— is not spontaneous’
- Ξ( ): predicate: " ____ is spontaneous."

A process that is not of the spontaneous type can be represented as belonging to the negation (‘not’) or complement (‘other’) of the spontaneous type: namely, the other types: the category called ‘non-spontaneous’ (ΔS < 0) and the one called ‘equilibrium’ (ΔS = 0).

**Q.Is Argument A Valid?**
Argument A = {Premises (P1-P9) ∴  Conclusion (C)}, where the symbol ∴ denotes ‘therefore’.

**Argument A**
P1. ‘Non-spontaneous’ = ‘not spontaneous’ | by def.’n & by L_ID: Law of Identity: (X = X)

P2. Spontaneous is (ΔS > 0)

P3. Not spontaneous is ~(ΔS > 0) |by: {P3, P4}

P4. ~(ΔS > 0) <=> (ΔS >/> 0): i.e., 'ΔS is not greater than zero'.

P5. (ΔS ≯ > 0) <=> (ΔS≤0)| logical complement.

P6. ~(ΔS > 0) <=> (ΔS≤0)| by {P5,P6}

P7. (ΔS≤0) is non-spontaneous | by {P2, P4}

P8. Every process is either spontaneous (ΔS > 0) or it is not spontaneous. L_EM: Law of Excluded Middle: (X V ~X).

P9. In physics, non-spontaneous refers to only (ΔS < 0)

---

C. Logically speaking, the physics convention is logically unsound | by {P8, P9}

Argument A is valid: {P1 - P9} |= C:
that is, premises P1 through P9 entail the conclusion C
(i.e., premises: {P1 - P9} logically imply the conclusion C).

The definition of non-spontaneous is at issue here. A process must either be spontaneous or not. A process cannot be neither spontaneous (ΔS > 0) nor not spontaneous (i.e., non-spontaneous): {physics: (ΔS < 0), logic: (ΔS ≤0}, but according to the physics notation, there can be: namely, (ΔS = 0) falls under the negation of (ΔS > 0): i.e., (ΔS = 0) ∈ (ΔS ≯ > 0), where (ΔS ≯ > 0) <=> (ΔS ≤0).

I have made a case for why the physics nomenclature violates the law of excluded middle.

What am I missing? Is it a matter of having the right knowledge of physics or of logic?

What, if any, mistakes have I made in thinking? Please let me know.

Comment: I think you are setting up a problem that does not exist. Physicists do not attach the same significance to terms like *spontaneous* and *non-spontaneous* that you do. What matters to us is the entropy change not the words you use to describe it. For what it's worth, a *reversible* process is an ideal that doesn't exist in the real world since any reversible change would have to take an infinite time to be reversible.

Comment: It seems that your argument could be summarised as follows: "in the term 'non-spontaneous,' the prefix 'non-' does not mean the same thing as the logical not, and I don't like it." Is that what you're trying to say here?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "spontaneous" and "not spontaneous" is not about the sign of the change in entropy. To quote [wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_process):

> In thermodynamics, a spontaneous process is a process which occurs without input of matter or electrical energy into the system.

The second law is then the assertion

> spontaneous $\Longrightarrow \Delta S \geq 0$

This does not imply that a process which is not spontaneous must decrease entropy (which is not true).